# Best way to save data of many instances

Tags: java, optimization, lwjgl

I have a particle system and for that I render (for 1 particle effect for example) 100 quads with texture on it. If I add several particle effects it lags because each particle has its own velicity (2f vector), position (3f vec), etc... (Vectors are from LwJGL)

As a consequence each instance means like 5 or 6 data types. Now my question is:

Is there a way of making this better, so that not every instance has 5 new vectors? (And I know, that there are many other better ways of creating a particle system, but this one I choose was easy and I can practice "performance boosting"..

Comment: Do all the quads have the same size? How do you calculate the velocity/position/etc? Would it be possible to transfer the algorithm in the shader?

Comment: Yeah, the quads all have the same size. I dont think, that I can transfer the algorithm in the shader. The velocity is velocity += constant.Gravity * gravityEffect * elapsedTime, the position is calculated by add the velocity vector to the current position

Comment: It sounds like feasible, which opengl version are you using? Please show us shaders and complete algorithm to render the quads

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d7e57c0777c009729bee9fde0f669081, if you need any more information feel free to ask and thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, I will refer to this [code](https://github.com/yashiro32/OpenGL-Rendering-Android/blob/master/src/en/menghui/android/gameengine/particles/ParticleRenderer.java) where you probably get inspired by.

I also suppose you have at least GL 3.3 profile.

In theory, to optimaze at best you should move `Map<ParticleTexture, List<Particle>> particles` (using a texture atlas) on the gpu and upload only the changing data per-frame, like `camera`. 
But this is not easy to do in one step, so I suggest you to modify your current algorithm step by step by moving one thing at time on the gpu.

Some observations:

- in `prepare()` and `finishRendering()`, the enabling of the i-th VertexAttribArray is part of the vao, if you bind/unbind the vao, it's enough. `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glDisableVertexAttribArray` can be removed
- use uniform buffer, don't have all those single uniforms alone.
- `loader.updateVbo()` is quite [expensive](https://github.com/yashiro32/OpenGL-Rendering-Android/blob/1a9afe69d061c29a6c53a96d5d29d46c964b8f21/src/en/menghui/android/gameengine/renderEngine/Loader.java#L97-L107), it creates a `FloatBuffer` every `render` and clear the buffer before copying the data.
  You should allocate a `float []` or a `FloatBuffer` just once, reuse it and call simply `glBufferSubData`, avoiding `glBufferData`

Comment: the first tip doesn't work for me... If I comment the lines with enableVertex out, it doesn't render the particles anymore

Comment: And to the third aspect: How do I do this? I understand the concept but I don't know, how excactly I reuse the buffer...

Comment: Then you are modifying the `vao` somewhere else. Remember that you do need to save at least once which vertex attribute shall be enable and with which layout (`glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glVertexAttribPointer`).
For the second, you can simply define `FloatBuffer buf = createFloatBuffer(data.length)` outside `updateVbo()`, to make it constant.

Comment: To be onest I don't get ur second point. In updateVbo() I never directly use createFloatBuffer and in ParticleRender I have a constant buffer So could you pls clarify, what you mean? :)

Comment: `updateVbo()` [does call](https://github.com/yashiro32/OpenGL-Rendering-Android/blob/1a9afe69d061c29a6c53a96d5d29d46c964b8f21/src/en/menghui/android/gameengine/renderEngine/Loader.java#L98) `createFloatBuffer`, which in turns allocates a new `Buffer`

Comment: Ahh, now I got it. It's in the code that you linked but not in mine :D. Your linked code is a bit different then mine, I never create a floatbuffer every frame :P

Comment: And I'm pretty sure that `vboData = new float[particlesList.size() * INSTANCE_DATA_LENGTH];` creates a memory leak but I don't know why and how I should fix this. Could you maybe have a look at that? :s

Comment: If the particlesList is always the same, allocate it once externally and re-use it